# Oracle PL/SQL - Exit begin end block if condition is not met

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, skip

Is it possible to exit/skip from a `begin end` block if a condition is not met?

Example:

```sql
DECLARE
    my_var BOOLEAN := TRUE;

BEGIN
    IF my_var THEN
        EXIT_BEGIN_END_HERE;  -- Exits the block but continue execution after it!
    END IF;

    -- Other stuff happens here. Won't be executed if IF above is true
    INSERT INTO asdf
    VALUES ('asdf', 'asdf');
END;

-- Other stuff happens here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GOTO` with a label:

```sql
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    my_var BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  BEGIN
    IF my_var THEN
      GOTO skip_insert;
    END IF;

    -- Other stuff happens here. Won't be executed if IF above is true
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'This should be skipped' );
  END;
  <<skip_insert>>
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Continue from here.' );
END;
/
```

Or use `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF`:

```sql
DECLARE
  my_var BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
  IF my_var THEN
    NULL
  ELSE
    -- Other stuff happens here. Won't be executed if IF above is true
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'This should be skipped' );
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Continue from here.' );
END;
/
```

Which both output:

> ```
> Continue from here.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=02310803b50e98a9a659c19d58280ce3)*

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is a better example (and solution) that illustrates what you are trying to achieve.

```
DECLARE
    my_var BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        IF my_var THEN
            RAISE PROGRAM_ERROR;
        END IF;
        -- Other stuff happens here. Won't be executed if IF above is true
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not here!');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
    END;
    -- Other stuff happens here
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Continuing.');
END;
```

You only want to exit the inner BEGIN-END, right? So you can use the [RAISE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/RAISE-statement.html#GUID-5F58843F-84C8-4768-A7B3-0E318948A88B) statement.
If you run the above code, it will display *Continuing.*

Comment: you should catch only the specific exception you raise.

Comment: Raising an exception is for when an error has occurred; this leaves a bad code smell as nothing bad has occurred in the OP's code and this is abusing exceptions to divert the program's flow. Yes, it would work but I would object to using this method if I was performing a code-review (especially if you were catching `OTHERS` rather than catching a user-defined exception).

Answer (score -2):

If one wants to exit from the outermost block then `RETURN` can be used:

```sql
DECLARE
    my_var BOOLEAN := TRUE;

BEGIN
    IF my_var THEN
        RETURN;  -- Exits the block but continue execution after it!
    END IF;

    -- Other stuff happens here. Won't be executed if IF above is true
    INSERT INTO asdf
    VALUES ('asdf', 'asdf');
END;

-- Other stuff happens here
```

Note that as pointed by @MT0, since this exits from the outermost block then the `INSERT INTO asdf` bellow won't be executed:

```sql
DECLARE
    my_var BOOLEAN := TRUE;

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        IF my_var THEN
            RETURN;  -- Exits the outermost block but continue execution after it!
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO qwerty
        VALUES ('qwerty', 'qwerty');
    END;

    -- Other stuff happens here. Won't be executed if IF above is true
    INSERT INTO asdf
    VALUES ('asdf', 'asdf');
END;

-- Other stuff happens here
```

`RETURN` can also be used inside procedures.

See similar question: [Abort a PL/SQL program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891458/abort-a-pl-sql-program)

Comment: This does not continue execution from a after the current nested PL/SQL block; it terminates the outer-most block [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=891a2342342158a2884c7342e1bf0978)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you. I will update the answer with this information!